# If $f^3(x)+f(x)=x+e^x$ then $f(x)=x$ has at least one solution in the interval $(1,3)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let an $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such as $f^3(x)+f(x)=x+e^x$.  Show that the equation $f(x)=x$ has at least one solution in the interval $(1,3)$. 
I was able to prove that $f$ is increasing and continuous but couldn't proceed more.

Thank you

Comment: I was able to prove that $f$ is increasing and continuous but couldn't proceed more

Comment: Better to show your effort in the question, rather than in comments.

Comment: Can you confirm the interval is $(1,3)$ and not something else?

Comment: I just added the comment to the question.

Comment: I have found this from an old school book, I don't know if there is a typo

Comment: Can you show that $f(1) > 1$? And that $f(3) < 3$?

Comment: $f(x)(f^{2}(x)+1)=x+e^{x} \Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{x+e^{x}}{f^{2}(x)+1} \leq x+e^{x}$. Hence $f(1) \leq 1+e$ and $f(3) \leq 3+e^{3}$.

Comment: Is that $f^3(x) = (f(x))^3$ or $f(f(f(x)))$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f^3(1)+f(1)=1+e^1>3\Rightarrow f(1)>1$ similarly $f^3(3)+f(3)=1+e^3<30\Rightarrow f(3)<3$  thus $f(x)-x$ has at least a root in $(1,3)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y_1 = f(1)$, $y_3 = f(3)$

Let 
$$P(x):= x^3 + x - 1 - e  $$

Now, $y_1$ is a root of $P$, $P(x)$ is monotonically increasing, and $P(1) < 0$, which implies that $y_1 > 1 \iff y_1 - 1 >0$

Similarly, define

$$Q(x):= x^3 + x - 3 - e^3$$

$y_3$ is a root of $Q$, which is increasing. Note that $Q(3) > 0$, which implies $y_3 - 3 < 0$

Lastly,

$$h(x):= f(x) - x$$

is continuous, $h(1) > 0$, and $h(3) < 0$, so $h$ has a root in $(1,3)$.